# Trying to set up Jeckyll: ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError) undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, ubuntu-14.04, github-pages

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 trying to set up Jeckyll for gitHub pages using this procedure: https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages/

I'm relatively new to linux, so I largely have no idea what I'm doing when it comes to troubleshooting.  I hope someone here can get me pointed in the right direction.

I'm trying to do step 2 in the prcedure linked above.  `gem install bundler`.  It seems I've messed something up somewhere (or I'm missing dependencies?).  In any case, it seems something is wrong with gem, and inparticular with `gem install`.  If I do `which gem`, I get `/usr/local/bin/gem`.

But `gem install` gives the following error:

```
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

So I tried making sure zlib was installed, but it looks like I already had it?

```
$ sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version.
zlib1g-dev set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
```

So then I looked at `gem install help` and got some interesting output... it looks like there are a bunch of missing commands including the `install` command?? What's up with that?:

```
$ gem help commands
ERROR:  Loading command: build (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  Loading command: cert (NameError)
    uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::CertCommand
ERROR:  Loading command: check (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  Loading command: generate_index (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  Loading command: pristine (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  Loading command: push (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  Loading command: server (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  Loading command: specification (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  Loading command: unpack (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- zlib
GEM commands are:

    build             [No command found for build]
    cert              [No command found for cert]
    check             [No command found for check]
    cleanup           Clean up old versions of installed gems
    contents          Display the contents of the installed gems
    dependency        Show the dependencies of an installed gem
    environment       Display information about the RubyGems environment
    fetch             Download a gem and place it in the current directory
    generate_index    [No command found for generate_index]
    help              Provide help on the 'gem' command
    install           [No command found for install]
    list              Display local gems whose name matches REGEXP
    lock              Generate a lockdown list of gems
    mirror            Mirror all gem files (requires rubygems-mirror)
    open              Open gem sources in editor
    outdated          Display all gems that need updates
    owner             Manage gem owners of a gem on the push server
    pristine          [No command found for pristine]
    push              [No command found for push]
    query             Query gem information in local or remote repositories
    rdoc              Generates RDoc for pre-installed gems
    search            Display remote gems whose name matches REGEXP
    server            [No command found for server]
    sources           Manage the sources and cache file RubyGems uses to search
                      for gems
    specification     [No command found for specification]
    stale             List gems along with access times
    uninstall         Uninstall gems from the local repository
    unpack            [No command found for unpack]
    update            [No command found for update]
    which             Find the location of a library file you can require
    yank              Remove a pushed gem from the index
```

Any thoughts?

Also, here's the output of `gem environment` incase it's helpful:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.0
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.3 (2015-08-18 patchlevel 173) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/amy/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/amy/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0
     - /home/amy/.gem/ruby/2.2.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/games
```

Anyway, I'm totally lost.